# MYSQL Select the movie and vote average in single query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two mysql tables

votes:

```
user
movieid
starCount
```

movies:

```
id
title
description
```

I want to get `id,title,description,avg(starCount)` for every movie in table.

I tried:

```
select id,title,description,avg(starCount) 
from movies 
join votes on movies.id=votes.movieid
```

Comment: You missed `group by`: `select m.id,m.title,m.description,avg(v.starCount) from movies m inner join votes v on m.id=v.movieid group by m.id,m.title,m.description`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query looks pretty good, you are just missing a `GROUP BY` clause:

```
select m.id, m.title, m.description, avg(v.starCount) 
from movies m
join votes v on movies.id = votes.movieid
group by m.id, m.title, m.description
```

Every non-aggregated column must be declared in the `GROUP BY` clause: this applies to all columns that you select from `movies`. On the other hand, `votes.starCount` is aggregated by function `AVG`, hence it does not need to be part of the `GROUP BY` clause.